# Why does my youtube embed play behind my modalviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, modalviewcontroller

I am building an app for iphone ios 4+ and I have a modal view controller with a uiwebview inside that loads a page that contains a youtube embed.  When I play the youtube video it plays behind my modal view controller!  How can I either:
Find out when the video plays so i can hide my modal view controller
or
Make the video play on top of everything
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this behavior to replicate in the simulator.  How is the video embedded? As an iframe, or the old 'object' method?  What type of view does you Modal view present from?  `UIView` or `UITableView`...

Like I said I can't replicate your results on the 4.3 simulator, and this is the code I'm implementing.

```
NSURLRequest* urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.quietsight.com/youtube_embed.php"]];
[_webView loadRequest:urlReq];
```

On the iOS end, and on the web end...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fMJTinMvB24" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

As far as a call back on the video ending I don't believe there is a way to tell that a video is playing from a WebView.

Comment: ill create a small sample app to reproduce this issue this evening and post

Comment: Cool, that would be really helpful.